# How to call redirect_to in Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, redirecttoaction

I want to call redirect_to function in the Delayed job.
I have file print_job.rb

```
class PrintJob < Struct.new(:device,:survey,:filter_tags,:day1,:day2,:lastsurvey, :scale)
  def perform
    pc = PagesController.new
    pc.redirect_to  "http://google.com"
    #pc.redirect_to :action => "print", :format => "pdf", :device => device, :survey => survey, :filter_tags => filter_tags,
    #:day1 => day1, :day2 => day2, :lastsurvey => lastsurvey, :scale => scale
  end

  def success(job)
  end
end
```

but it does not work. If I just put redirect_to "htpp://google.com". It said that no method redirect_to

The current situation now is I am using pdf kit with delayed_job but not exporting a pdf file directly. I have link locahost/print If i want to open it in format pdf, just put localhost/print.pdf or using link_to :action => "print", :format => "pdf" But if the pdf file is big, it does not have well performance so I want to open localhost/print.pdf in delayed_job. So how can I solve this problem

So how can I call redirect_to in delayed job now? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`delayed_job`, are designed run long processes in background with out interrupting the http request of the rails controller. So it works like

- 1) controller gets a request
- 2) controller calls the delayed job and pass the 'long running'
  process
- 3) controller move on without waiting for reply from delayed job

So in that context, what you asked is kind of 'strange', however , if your requirement is to notify the user, etc.. once the process is completed,

a) update a database column by the `delayed_job` and read it from your view
b) use some kind of a `server-push` method, its [built-in to rails4](http://ngauthier.com/2013/02/rails-4-sse-notify-listen.html), or using a gem like [Faye](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails/)

HTH

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. The current situation now is I am using pdf kit with delayed_job but not exporting a pdf file directly.

I have link http://locahost/print
If i want to open it in format pdf, just put http://localhost/print.pdf or using link_to :action => "print", :format => "pdf"

But if the pdf file is big, it does not have well performance so I want to open http://localhost/print.pdf in delayed_job.

So how can I solve this problem

Comment: in that case the best way I could think of is, implement some kind of a server push notification system, so once the delayed job is over it will send a push notification to the client browser, like u get the notifications in stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you could just use the database (one status column) and proceed that way (worker updates column, page some how auto refresh and get column values constantly) but right now at this time, i would highly recommend the use of [active cable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) (which right now is part of rails 5+)

With [active cable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) you can easily create a communication channel between your views or controllers and any worker, all you have to do is to setup a channel for your user and then send the messages from the worker while you already have a the listener (view with js code) that will get broadcast messages from the channel common channel (common between the view and worker using the same name/id etc this is really just a string representing the channel name, the js code (front end) will have it as well as the rails (back end) config)

Hope this helps!